# csh inline math

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I need to do some integer math in **csh** (and no, other shells are not an option, nor is bc, nor is perl, nor is python, period).

In **bash** my task would look like

```
seq 1 1 10 > m.txt  #supplied from elsewhere
a=2                 #supplied from elsewhere
b=3                 #supplied from elsewhere
head -n $[$a*$b] m.txt # the line in question
```

then the question is *Is there an expression in csh that computes* `$[$a*$b]` *inline?*
I know that I can do `@ c = $a * $b` in csh, but that's not inline. I did a little bit of googling and searching SO, but no success so far, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your use of square-brackets meant to indicate an array notation or matrix math? csh has no such built-in features.

ELSE, if you mean like bash `$(($a * $b))`, you can use csh cmd-substitution with backquotes to give you

```
head -n `expr $a \* $b` m.txt
```

Note that if your goal was to avoid spawning extra processes, this does not meet your goal, but it is "in-line"

**Edit** I see I mistyped as `$( $a * $b )`, see inline correction above.

IHTH.

Comment: The square bracket syntax is literal bash arithmetic substitution.  `$[`...`]` is the same as `$((`...`))`; it computes an arithmetic expression, but unlike the dollarless version, it is replaced by the result: `let a=3 b=2; echo $((a*b))`

Comment: I'm aware of `$(( ... ))` and use it all the time in ksh. Didn't know about `$[ ..]`. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about `$[...]` in bash and was just wondering if there was something with exactly the same functionality in csh, and didn't know about `expr`, will try and thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2):

Without using something outside of the shell, no.

The usual culprit for math from old school shell scripts is `expr`:

```
head -n `expr $a \* $b` m.txt
```

but if that's just as *verboten* as `bc` *et al*, then you're out of luck. Period.

Comment: Well, `expr` is better than nothing, I'll try that, although you're right, might as well use bc then...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not pretty:

```
% seq 1 1 10 > m.txt
% set a = 2
% set b = 3
% head -n `@ tmp = $a * $b ; echo $tmp ; unset tmp` m.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Note that this will clobber `$tmp` if you happen to have a variable of that name, so choose a unique name.

(Though I wonder why bc, perl, and python are not an option.)

Comment: Well, the reason is that I just was wondering if csh had something equvalent to bash's `$[...]` or `$((...))`. I guess I could have just asked that, but the example i gave seemed more precise. Thank you for your answer!